# Issue or confusion with JMS/spring/AMQ not processing messages asynchronously

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

We have a situation where we set up a component to run batch jobs using spring batch remotely.  We send a JMS message with the job xml path, name, parameters, etc. and we wait on the calling batch client for a response from the server.

The server reads the queue and calls the appropriate method to run the job and return the result, which our messaging framework does by:

```
    this.jmsTemplate.send(queueName, messageCreator);
    this.LOGGER.debug("Message sent to '" + queueName + "'");

    try {
        final Destination replyTo = messageCreator.getReplyTo();
        final String correlationId = messageCreator.getMessageId();

        this.LOGGER.debug("Waiting for the response '" + correlationId + "' back on '" + replyTo + "' ...");
        final BytesMessage message = (BytesMessage) this.jmsTemplate.receiveSelected(replyTo, "JMSCorrelationID='"
                + correlationId + "'");
        this.LOGGER.debug("Response received");
```

Ideally, we want to be able to call out runJobSync method twice, and have two jobs simultaneously operate.  We have a unit test that does something similar, without jobs.  I realize this code isn't very great, but, here it is:

final List result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.pingWithDelaySync(1000); 
            result.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }, "thread1");

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.pingWithDelaySync(500);              
            result.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }, "thread2");

    thread1.start();
    Thread.sleep(250);
    thread2.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    Assert.assertEquals("both thread finished", 2, result.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("thread2 finished first", "thread2", result.get(0));
    Assert.assertEquals("thread1 finished second", "thread1", result.get(1));
```

When we run that test, thread 2 completes first since it just has a 500 millisencond wait, while thread 1 does a 1 second wait:

```
Thread.sleep(delayInMs);
    return result;
```

That works great.
When we run two remote jobs in the wild, one which takes about 50 seconds to complete and one which is designed to fail immediately and return, this does not happen.

Start the 50 second job, then immediately start the instant fail job.  The client prints that we sent a message requesting that the job run, the server prints that it received the 50 second request, but waits until that 50 second job is completed before handling the second message at all, even though we use the ThreadPoolExecutor.

We are running transactional with Auto acknowledge.

Doing some remote debugging, the Consumer from AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer shows no unhandled messages (so consumer.receive() obviously just returns null over and over).  The webgui for the amq broker shows 2 enqueues, 1 deque, 1 dispatched, and 1 in the dispatched queue.  This suggests to me that something is preventing AMQ from letting the consumer "have" the  second message.  (prefetch is 1000 btw)
This shows as the only consumer for the particular queue.

Myself and a few other developers have poked around for the last few days and are pretty much getting nowhere.  Any suggestions on either, what we have misconfigured if this is expected behavior, or, what would be broken here.

Does the method that is being remotely called matter at all?  Currently the job handler method uses an executor to run the job in a different thread and does a future.get() (the extra thread is for reasons related to logging).

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

not sure I follow completely, but off the top, you should try the following...

- set the concurrentConsumers/maxConcurrentConsumers greater than the default (1) on the MessageListenerContainer
- set the prefetch to 0 to better promote balancing messages between consumers, etc.